# How to mock FindResources?

Tags: wpf, moq

FindResources is non virtual method and any interfaces implement it.

Is there any way to mock this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out MS Moles:  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

This is a free isolation framework that will allow you to mock static methods and other "unmockables".  Typemock isolation framework is also an option, but Moles is free.

This can't be accomplished with Moq.

Comment: 3rd alternative: Telerick JustMock. LOTS cheaper than TypeMock.

Answer (score 1):

The FrameworkElement class which has the FindResources method is a class, not an interface.

You cannot mock it using moq.

And since FindResources is non-virtual, you cannot derive and override it.

Comment: -1. You CAN mock it, just not with one of the usual open sourcem ockers. Try Telerik JustMock or MS Moles. Both can moch even static methods. JustMock is about 250 USD.